# How to have a whole division in same page, instead of breaking in the middle in HTML

Tags: html

In a document, if we reach near end and a new division is starting there, it's breaking up into parts, and breaking into different pages. How to write the whole division into 2nd page, leaving the small blank space remaining in the 1st page?

Comment: what does that even mean? Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: You mean to divide a single page with two different html codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is done with CSS: set [`page-break-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)`: avoid` on the division element. Depending on browser support, this may or may not work.

Using `page-break-before: always` instead might work somewhat more often, but at the cost of being less flexible—it might cause an almost blank page even though the division would well fit in.

Comment: Thank you very much Jukka K. Korpela. This is what I need, page-break-inside attribute.